# Pass multiple controller names in Route Config default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to do Route Configuration Like Bellow,

http://domain.com/AboutMe Then it will go Home Controller - AboutMe Action
http://domain.com/ContactMe Then it will go Home Controller - ContactMe Action

It is working fine for following Route Config,

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Custom",
               url: "{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home"  }
);
```

but following links are not working,

http://domain.com/Login Then it will go Login Controller - Login Action
http://domain.com/RegisterMe Then it will go Login Controller - RegisterMe Action

So here is my quetion,

Can i pass multiple controllers names while route configuration, so it will search my actions in Home & Account both controllers,

i.e. something like,

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Custom",
               url: "{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home,Account"  }
);
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Custom",
               url: "{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = new string[] { "Home", "Account"  }
);
```

Comment: No, that's not possible because the routing engine wouldn't know which controller to use. A simple `{controller}/{action}` route would achieve what you need.

Comment: You should either create one controller to hold those two actions, or create separate routes